# Plotting a heatmap using CSV file data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, heatmap

I have output nested dictionary variable called **all_count_details_dictionary**. Using that variable I saved data to the CSV file using the following command.

```
import pandas as pd
csv_path = '../results_v6/output_01.csv'
# creating pandas dataframe using concat mehtod to extract data from dictionary
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(l) for l in all_count_details_dictionary],axis=1).T

# saving the dataframe to the csv file
df.to_csv(csv_path, index=True)
```

The output CSV file is just like as below

[image]
The CSV file can be download using this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rzKJniGBOgNBw7EN3cv3TD6I40p4jTil/view?usp=sharing)

So I used the following code to plot a graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def extract_csv_gen_plot(csv_path):

    length = 1503 #len(dataframe_colums_list)
    data = np.genfromtxt(csv_path, delimiter=",", skip_header=True, usecols=range(3, (length+1)))
    print(data)

    # renaming data axes
    #fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #fig.canvas.draw()

    #labels =[item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
    #labels[1] = 'testing'
    #ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

    #ax.set_xticklabels(list)
    #ax.set_yticklabels(list)
    #plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90)


    plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot',interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
```

I tried to get the column labels and case details labels into the graph axes, but it doesn't work out. Can anyone please tell me there is any other best method to plot this table into a heat map than this?

Thank you!

Comment: It would help if your data example was not an image (i.e. raw CSV text) as it could then be copy / pasted to test your script. You can use the [edit] button to improve your question.

Comment: I have uploaded the CSV file. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Pandas, the labels are picked up automatically:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def extract_csv_gen_plot(csv_path):

    data = pd.read_csv(csv_path, index_col=1)
    data = data.drop(data.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1)
    data.index.names = ['Name']
    g = sns.heatmap(data)
    g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
    g.set_title('Heatmap')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


extract_csv_gen_plot("output_01.csv")
```

[image: seaborn heatmap]

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the result that I expected. It works perfectly. Thank you once again.

Comment: I have a small question. why didn't it give the actual x-axis and y-axis values when hovering through the heatmap. Is there any method I can use?

Comment: Not tried that with matplotlib, you could investigate bokeh

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Seaborn, they have a heatmap plotting function that works very well with Pandas DataFrames

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(data)
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html